# Why does my footer shift onto the sidebar whenever changes made to singles.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, footer, sidebar

I am trying to make tags visible on WordPress posts, just below the content.

**My original code** (just the end part):

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>            

<div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <p style="text-align : center; font-size : 13px;">Views presented in the article are those of the author and not of ED.</p>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

**My modified code:**

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <p>
        <?php $posttags=get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo $tag->name . ' '; } } ?>
    </p>

    <p style="text-align : center; font-size : 13px;">Views presented in the article are those of the author and not of ED.</p>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

**What I intended to do:**

Make tags appear below the content.

**What happened:**

The tags never show up. (Even after emptying the cache; even when they do , they just come out wrong - that's another issue.)

***The footer shifts to the sidebar.***

**How do I avoid the footer from getting into the sidebar?**

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax

```
$posttags=g et_the_tags();
```

Should be

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
```

Notice the space in "get_the_tags();"

Comment: That was a typo in the question. Sorry. Not my actual code. Changing it.